# Is there a equivalent Debezium command to starting Kafka Connect without Docker container

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

The debezium kafka connect command is :
`docker run -it --rm --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka --link mysql:mysql debezium/connect:0.9`

Is there an equivalent way to not run inside a docker container with flags to specify the zookeeper instance and kafka bootstrap servers/broker ?  I have my kafka and zookeeper running on my mac locally but not inside a docker container .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "flags", just properties files. The docker image is just using variable substitution inside of those files.

You can [refer to the Debezium installation documentation](https://debezium.io/docs/install/stable/), and it is just a plugin to Kafka Connect, which is included with your Kafka installation.

Find `connect-standalone.properties` in your Kafka install to get started. One important property you will want to edit is `plugin.path`, which must be the full parent path to where you put the Debezium JAR files. Then Kafka is configured there as well

Then you would run this to start a single node

```
connect-standalone.sh connect-standalone.properties your-debezium-config.properties
```

(Docker image is running `connect-distributed.sh`, but you wouldn't need to run a Cluster just on your Mac)

Comment: Can you show your-debezium-config.properties schema?
Is this here?
```"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "mysql",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "debezium",
    "database.password": "dbz",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "database.whitelist": "inventory",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.inventory",
    "name": "inventory-connector"```

Comment: @MasterLuV `connect-standalone` takes Java Properties files (lines of `key=value`), not JSON

Comment: @cricket_007: Thank you! How can i know what is required property? I can't see in the document

Comment: @MasterLuV In your existing Kafka installation, you can find a documented `connect-standalone.properties`. The other property file is the exact same properties from the JSON, only not JSON, just `key=vaule` pairs on each line.